# Reference to current object in constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to define a class that, in its constructor, instantiates other objects and passes them a reference to itself:

```
var Child = function(m) {
  var mother = m;

  return {
    mother: mother
  }
}

var Mother = function() {
  var children = makeChildren();

  return {
    children: children
  }

  function makeChildren() {
    var children = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var c = new Child(this);      // <--- 'this' is an empty object here
      children.push(c)
    }
    return children;
  }
}
```

This doesn't work, and the Child instances end up with an empty object in their `mother` property. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript's `this` is not lexical. This means that `makeChildren` gets its *own* `this` instead of getting the `Mother`'s `this` you want.

Set a normal variable to this and use it instead.

```
var that = this;
function makeChildren(){
     blabla = that;
}
```

---

I don't think doing this is just enough though. By returning an object from the constructor you ignore the `this`. Set things into it:

```
this.children = children;
```

instead of returning a new object.

Comment: Setting `this.children = makeChildren()` worked. Is this a considered a better pattern in general than returning an object from the constructor?

Comment: Its just that when doing a constructor that uses the `new` syntax you get a `this` to work with (and the this inherits from the prototype, etc). If you plan on having a function that returns its own thing, not needing to acces this for inheritance or access to prototypal methods you might as well make it a normal non-constructor function. (And make the name non-capitalized. Convention reserves that for things that need the `new` operator)

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing a reference to the mother object when you call makeChildren() from within the mother object, something like this maybe:

```
var Mother = function() {
   var children = makeChildren(this);
}
```

The makeChildren() function can then accept as an argument the reference, which you can use:

```
function makeChildren(ref)
var c = new Child(ref);
```

No idea whether or not that will work, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Playing games with the magic `this` variable usually leaves one with missing feet.  I like this solution as it's simple, straight forward, and the fact that `makeChildren` doesn't have to be called in a special way in order for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A nested function does not inherit `this` from its parent, so the `this` within `makeChildren()` is not the same as the `this` within the Mother constructor unless you explicitly set it when calling `makeChildren()`:

```
var children = makeChildren.call(this);
```

That should work without any further changes to your code. Have a look at MDN for [more detail about .call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Alternatively you can save a reference to `this` and pass that into the function:

```
var Mother = function() {
  var self = this; // <-- new variable

  var children = makeChildren();

  return {
    children: children
  }

  function makeChildren() {
    var children = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var c = new Child(self);      // <--- change 'this' to 'self'
      children.push(c)
    }
    return children;
  }
}
```

Local variables within a function are accessible to nested functions.

Comment: the self variable would only be accessible from within the Mother function wouldn't it? Unless you explictly passed a reference through?

Comment: @jayp: inner functions can use all the variables in their scope and this includes varaibles from the outer function.

Comment: For some reason I thought makeChildren wasn't an inner function, but seperate - clearly I didn't read it properly. Thanks.

Comment: If `makeChildren` was a separate (non-inner) function the `.call` syntax would allow it to work. Or you could pass a reference through as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Child = function(m) {
    var mother = m;

    return {
        mother: mother
    }
};

var Mother = function() {
    if (!(this instanceof Mother)) {
        return new Mother();
    }

    var that = this;

    var makeChildren = function() {

        var children = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var c = new Child(that); // <--- 'that' is the reference to Mother
            children.push(c)
        }

        return children;
   };

   var children = makeChildren();

   return {
       children: children
   }   
};
```

then do:

```
var m = Mother();
```

The first three lines in the `Mother` object ensure that the value of `that` is the `Mother` instance and not the global object. Without them, you would always have to write:

```
var m = new Mother();
```